# select places with nearly same location (duplicates) by latitude/longitude

Tags: mysql, sql, gps, latitude-longitude

Lets say I have a table `venues` with following columns:

```
id
user_id
name
latitude
longitude
```

The latitude and longitude are kept as FLOAT(10,6) values. As different users add venues, there are venue duplicates. How can I select all the duplicates from the table in range up to lets say 50 metres (as it might be hard to achieve as the longitudial meter equivalents are different at different latitudes, so this is absolutely aproximate)? The query should select all venues: VenueA and VenueB (there might be VenueC, VenueD, etc) so that I can compare them. It should filter out venues that are actually one per location in the range (I care only for duplicates).

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It is far more efficient to detect duplicates when a new venue is added than afterwards, when the only practical approach is to check every venue against all other unchecked venues.  What is the reason for not checking venues as they are added?  In which case, the previously suggested approaches are effective, although best results will be achieved by using the haversine formula, which can be incorporated in a query that also does a simple check on a latitude range.  The latter can use an index, while haversine cannot readily do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for an answer but had to settle with answering myself.

```
SELECT s1.id, s1.name, s2.id, s2.name FROM venues s1, venues s2
WHERE s2.id > s1.id AND 
(POW(s1.latitude - s2.latitude, 2) + POW(s1.longitude - s2.longitude, 2) < 0.001)
```

The first condition is to select only half of matrix as order of similar venues is not important. The second one is simplified distance calculator. As user185631 suggested haversine formula should do the trick if you need more precision but I didn't need it as I was looking for duplicates with the same coordinates but couldn't settle with s1.latitude = s2.latitude AND s1.longitude = s2.longitude due to float/decimal corruption in my DB.

Of course checking this at insert would be better but if you get corrupt DB you need to clean it somehow. Please also note that this query is heavy on server if your tables are big.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which computes distances between lat/lons.  For small/less accurate distance (which is the case here) you can use the Equirectangular approximation (see section here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).  If the distance is less than your chosen threshold (50m), then it is a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Determine what 50 meters is in terms of lat and long. Then plus and minus that to your starting location to come up with a max and min for both lat and long. Then...

```
SELECT id FROM venues WHERE latitude < (your max latitude) AND latitude > (your min latitude) AND longitude < (your max longitude) AND longitude > (your min longitude);
```

Converting meters to lat/long is very tricky as it depends on where the starting point is on the globe. See the middle section of the page here: http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/utmformulas.htm

Comment: I can determine what 50 meters is in terms of lat and long but how would this select me duplicates from the table? I want a query that gives me all the duplicates and not one that checks if there is a duplicate of a certain lat/lng (this is easy but has nothing to do with my question)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you had a target location and wanted locations that were essentially duplicates of it.

Comment: @Veseliq: Easy, friend. A 'please' goes further than a downvote and a Schwartzenegger-toned comment. :)

Comment: @Veseliq: It's all good, man. Just realize we're not working for upvotes, so a little politeness goes a long way. On another note, I think there *is* value in the part of the answer that tells about converting from meters to lat/long, as it is not just a formula. It's actually very complicated. See the link. Good luck!